# How to leave vertical space for the youtube link?

Tags: html, css

[image: Background Image and Text]

The orange scroll block goes up and down but I wanted the default position of that orange icon to be more toward the bottom of the screen below the title Odyssey. I am new to css so just needed some help for the same.

/* Home Style */

```
#tf-home{
    background: url(../images/OdysseyTitleImage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

#tf-home .overlay{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%, rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73)), color-stop(35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66)), color-stop(62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 }

.home-lead{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
    font-size: 21px;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
    padding: 15% 0 0;
}
.content-game{
    position: relative;
    padding: 5% 0 5%;
}
.color{
    color: #ff6300;
}

a.fa.fa-angle-down {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #b4b4b4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
a.fa.fa-angle-down:hover{
    background: #ff6300;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #ff6300;
}
.home-heading{
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

and this is the html

```
 <div id="tf-home" class="text-center">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="content">
            <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRlP0t41wCw" class="btn tf-btn btn-default popup-video">Watch the trailer</a></div>
            <a href="#tf-game" class="fa fa-angle-down page-scroll"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could just change the padding-top in this lines:

```
.content{
    position: relative;
    padding: 15% 0 0;
}
```

You can try something like `padding: 30% 0 0;`